# My parabola shifts along the x-axis as I change x-lim

Tags: r

I have some data on prices and a demand (quantity) equation from regression. Here's a `dput()` of the data for reproducibility:

https://gist.github.com/hack-r/28d0f6845eafc7935f6cbb74fdd09637

I'm trying to get a plot that looks like this one, so that I will know where the optimal price lies:

[image]

However, the [example](http://rpubs.com/jcreed/opplastersand) from which I got the plot above does not provide its data and omits some of the code, so I'm unclear how they were able to get this.

My data looks like this:

```
head(mydat)
```

> ```
>     gross_price      cost quantity net_price
> 204     895.000  47.51235       16  847.4877
> 159     920.000  66.10084        3  853.8992
> 149     950.000  75.67797        6  874.3220
> 201     895.000  13.03794       10  881.9621
> 217    1016.329 114.95628        9  901.3731
> 288    1132.306  90.63706       16 1041.6690
> ```

So, I did this:

```
par(mar = c(5,5,2,5))

with(mydat, plot(net_price, quantity,pch=1,xlab="Price",ylab="Quantity", xlim=c(0,1250),ylim=c(0,800)))
abline(a=(30.6117202), b=-0.0279182, col="green") # Demand Fn coef.s from regression

par(new = T)
mydat$predicted_q <- (30.6117202-0.0279182 * mydat$net_price) 
mydat$profit      <- mydat$predicted_q * mydat$net_price  # quantity * net price

with(mydat, plot(net_price, profit, type="l", col="red3",axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA))
```

Which gave me this:

[image: plot] - **note**: *at the time of writing Stack Overflow's image host (imgur.com) has a major outage, so I can't get the plot to display correctly, hence the link.*

But it looked like the red line (parabola) was a little right of center, so I tried changing the `xlim` to see what happened. Apparently the parabola stays in the same place regardless of the rest of the data. That's not good; it means we can't properly interpret the plot.

```
par(mar = c(5,5,2,5))

with(mydat, plot(net_price, quantity,pch=1,xlab="Price",ylab="Quantity", xlim=c(0,3000),ylim=c(0,800)))
abline(a=(30.6117202), b=-0.0279182, col="green") # Demand Fn coef.s from regression

par(new = T)
mydat$predicted_q <- (30.6117202-0.0279182 * mydat$net_price) 
mydat$profit      <- mydat$predicted_q * mydat$net_price  # quantity * net price

with(mydat, plot(net_price, profit, type="l", col="red3",axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA))
```

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/6971/r1gG6I.png

So I thought to myself that the problem must be that the parabola is being plotted on a different layer from the rest and perhaps I could solve this with `lines()`:

```
par(mar = c(5,5,2,5))

with(mydat, plot(net_price, quantity,pch=1,xlab="Price",ylab="Quantity", xlim=c(0,3000),ylim=c(0,800)))
abline(a=(30.6117202), b=-0.0279182, col="green") # Demand Fn coef.s from regression

par(new = T)
mydat$predicted_q <- (30.6117202-0.0279182 * mydat$net_price) 
mydat$profit      <- mydat$predicted_q * mydat$net_price  # quantity * net price

#with(mydat, plot(net_price, profit, type="l", col="red3",axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA))
lines(mydat$profit, col="red3",type="l")
```

But this result isn't even a nice smooth parabola, which is what I'd need for this to be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the first plot `xlim` to the parabola plot.

```
with(mydat, plot(net_price, profit, type="l", col="red3",axes=F, 
                 xlab=NA, ylab=NA,xlim=c(0,1250)))
```

https://imageshack.com/i/poFMW7asj

And

```
with(mydat, plot(net_price, profit, type="l", col="red3",axes=F,
                 xlab=NA, ylab=NA, xlim = c(0,3000)))
```

https://imageshack.com/i/pn0VYxikj

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! I'm going to tell myself that I would've realized this if it were not for the bad example that I was basing this on.

Comment: Had you set `axes=T` you would have come to realize that the parabola had different axes.

Comment: Right. Or `axis(side = 4)`. I was just following the example too blindly. I don't think the OP of the example I was using was aware of this problem.